# jQuery works only half the time

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, button, href

I have two "buttons" (liked/disliked) which are actually images attached to an href tag that when the user clicks, values are sent to my database. #Messages displays the output of check.php which simply returns the values. The jQuery code sits inside a loop along with the html for the buttons.

The weird thing is that my code works for only the Like button and only if the dislike button is removed from my code. The dislike button by itself (like button removed from code) doesn't work at all and if both buttons are coded, neither button works.

Also, the #like is supposed to display before the #dislike, but on my page #dislike appears to the left of #like, which is not what is supposed to happen (it should appear to the right of #like). Any ideas for that?

Begin loop:

```
<?php
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Contests");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $data )){
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userContests WHERE userID='$userID' AND contestID='$row[contestID]';") or die(mysql_error()); 
$checked = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
?>
```

My jQuery (if I remove #dislike, then #like works. If I remove #like, #dislike doesn't work. When both are present, neither works):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var checked = <?php echo $checked['value']; ?>;
    var postID = <?php echo $row['postID']; ?>;
    var userID = <?php echo $current_user->ID; ?>;

    if (checked == 1) {
        $('#post_<?php echo $row['postID']; ?>').addClass('like'); 
    } else if (checked == 0) {
        $('#post_<?php echo $row['postID']; ?>').addClass('dislike'); 
    }

    $('#like_<?php echo $row['postID']; ?>').click(function(liked) {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'check.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'userID=' + userID + '&postID=' + postID + '&value=' + '1',
            success: function(result) {
                $('#Message_<?php echo $row['postID']; ?>').html('').html(result).prependTo('#post_<?php echo $row['postID']; ?>');
            }
        });

        $('#post_<?php echo $row['postID']; ?>').removeClass('dislike').addClass('like');
        if (showLikes.attr('checked')) {
            $('#post_<?php echo $row['postID']; ?>').toggle();
        }
    });

    $('#dislike_<?php echo $row['postID']; ?>').click(function(disliked) {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'check.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'userID=' + userID + '&postID=' + postID + '&value=' + '0',
            success: function(result) {
                $('#Message_<?php echo $row['postID']; ?>').html('').html(result).prependTo('#post_<?php echo $row['postID']; ?>');
            }

        $('#post_<?php echo $row['postID']; ?>').removeClass('like').addClass('dislike'); 
        if (showDislikes.attr('checked')) {
            $('#post_<?php echo $row['postID']; ?>').toggle();
        }
    });
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="post_<?php echo $row['postID']; ?>" class="post">
<div id="post_<?php echo $row['postID']; ?>_inside">
    <div>
        <a id="like_<?php echo $row['postID']; ?>" class="like" href="#"><span></span></a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a id="dislike_<?php echo $row['postID']; ?>" class="dislike" href="#"><span></span></a>
    </div>
    <b><?php echo $row['Title']; ?></b><br>
    Expires: <?php echo $row['Exp']; ?><br>
    <ul id="listM"></ul> 
</div>
</div>
<div id="Message_<?php echo $row['postID']; ?>" class="reminder"></div>
```

End loop:

```
<?php 
} 
?>
```

My CSS:

```
a.like {
float: right;
background: url(images/entered.png) no-repeat top center;
height: 30px;
width: 28px;
}

a.like:active {
float: right;
background: url(images/entered.png) no-repeat bottom center;
height: 30px;
width: 28px;
}

a.dislike {
float: right;
background: url(images/not-interested.png) no-repeat top center;
height: 30px;
width: 28px;
}

a.dislike:active {
float: right;
background: url(images/not-interested.png) no-repeat bottom center;
height: 30px;
width: 28px;
}
```

So what could possibly be going on? If #like works without #dislike, then why won't #dislike work without #like?

Comment: (Still looking, but this code would be a great opportunity to practice refactoring ;) Is there just a single row, or is this inside a loop?

Comment: Also, can you possibly post the html output rather than the PHP? That would make looking into this much easier.

Comment: The html is inside a php loop.

So everywhere you see php, you are looking at a numerical value that represents the number of the post inside mysql. i.e #Message_1, #post_1, #post_1_inside, #like_1, #dislike_1 and so on.

I have updated the html code to show you my loop.

Comment: FYI to the person who gave -1 to my question, how is it uninformed or unclear?!

Comment: Not really related to your question, but why do you use two separate queries instead of a join?

Comment: Because I'm searching for two different things in two different tables: One is the list of posts and the other is the list of liked/disliked posts that match the logged in user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to solve the problem by inserting the value named value sent through ajax inside a variable.

I don't know why it doesn't work when hard-coded but there you go.